# How to exclude such pattern from regex matching?

Tags: javascript, regex

I would like to compose a regular expression to highlight keywords.

The regex is kind of like

```
\btap\b.
```

And for below sentence, it's expected to match only one "tap" without double quotation. But in reality, it also match the second "tap" within quotation symbol.

```
tap click "tap"
```

How can I exclude the second tap word from being matched?

Comment: Are you trying to match phrases with only _one_ `tap`, or are you looking for a regex which matches the _first_ `tap` ?

Comment: What language/tool are you using?

Comment: You may use lookarounds to disallow quotes around the word: [`(?<!")\btap(?!")\b`](https://regex101.com/r/oJ0vG4/1).

Comment: @stribizhev the problem with that is that it won't match `"tap` or `tap"`. The next question would be: is that a problem?

Comment: i am trying to match all the tap without double quotation...In my case, only tap should be matched

Comment: Then the regex by @stribizhev should do the job.  But you should also consider other types of quotes, punctuation (e.g. end of sentence `tap.`) etc.

Comment: i am using javascript

Comment: for example, if the sentence is tap click "tap" tap, then two tap word should be matched

Comment: @Chuck: That should have been added when you posted. As the regex tag info states, all questions with this tag should also include a tag specifying the applicable programming language or tool. Use `.replace(/(^|[^"])\b(tap)(?!")/g, "$1<span>$2</span>")` ([regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/xV1bY7/1)).

Comment: One trick would be to match `("?)\btap\b\1` and check if group 1 is empty or not.

Comment: `exclude the second tap word from being matched` ... in the above comment you implied you want to _include_ the two occurrences.  Can you please update your question with exactly what you are trying to do the JS code.

Comment: Be cautious with `\b`. JavaScript regexes do not use the Unicode definition of "letters", only ASCII. So `\b` will match the string "tap" if it occurs between non-ASCII alphabetic characters. Unicode support is only coming in ES6 with the `u` flag (not yet implemented in browsers).

Comment: One alternative that I always use is defining custom delimiters that behave similar to a word boundary: `'tap click "tap"'.replace(/(^|[^\w"-])tap/g, '$1XXX')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems working fine.

```
var reg = new RegExp('\\b(tap(?!\"))', 'ig')

('tap click "tap" tap.').match(reg)
```

> **Rules**
>
> 1. Starting word
> 2. not quotes at end
> 3. case insensitive.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ug8a4evL/)

Comment: I finally work this pattern for my requirement based on your answer.

\b((?<!\")tap(?!\"))\b

Answer (score 0):

Word boundaries `\b` matches any non-word character (so the `"` also).

You can simulate your own word boundaries where to include only what you think is appropriate.

In example:

`\s|^|\.|!|\?|$` - space or start of string, or dot, or exclamation mark, or question mark, or end of string

I would also suggest to use negative lookbehinds/-aheads but...

**Javascript doesn't support lookbehinds**

So you could use some capturing groups and then use the group which you need.

Sample regex: `(?:\s|^|\.|!|\?)(tap)(\s|$|\.|!|\?)`

And then in the javascript use the first capturing group - `match[1]`.

See [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/432503/5388552) for details how to use capturing groups in JavaScript.